# cd/dvd player not reading data cd's

Tags: cd-drive

In Ubuntu 12.04 on a DELL Latitude D630 laptop the cd/dvd player can read music cd's and movie dvd's and when a cd or dvd is inserted the device is properly listed under 'Devices' section on the File Manager.
However when I insert a CD with only data Ubuntu is not reading the CD and the device is not listed at all.
Can you please advise how to solve this problem?

I tried to mount the cd manually with the command line 'sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom' but I get the error message 'mount: no medium found on dev/sr0.

any idea?

Comment: I tried to mount the cd manually with the command line sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the drives firmware fails, and that might make the drive unable to read disks.  You may want to check with the manufacturer of the drive if a new firmware is available.
You also want to try a lens cleaner.